# Custom archive page for CPT UI

Tags: custom-post-types, archives

I have created a custom post type using CPT UI plugin, its slug is blog.
I created a custom page named archive-blog.php. But WordPress always takes default archive.php. I'm confused what to do. I tried to add functions available in different websites. I tried to put has archive to true in the CPT UI. Please help

Comment: Probably has to do with your slug choice.  Have you tried using something else?  I don't see `blog` on the reserved terms list but I would try another option first and go from there.

Comment: You could try creating a page with the slug 'blog' then using a page template instead.  This has worked for me in the past. WP will serve the page with slug 'blog' instead of the cpt archive for 'blog'.

Comment: @JasonMurray I already have a page template blog.